# TabStop de RadioButtons independente da propriedade Checked

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, radiobutton

Possuo um conjunto de RadioButtons, Edits e Labels dentro de um GroupBox, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que no uso do <kbd>Tab</kbd> o cursor não pare em nenhum RadioButton, pare somente nos Edits. Para isso, pensei em colocar `TabStop = False` em todos RadioButtons.

Curiosamente essa propriedade já é padrão `False` e há uma lógica (ou bug?), em que o RadioButton que esteja `Checked = True` funciona com `TabStop = True`, e todos os RadioButtons com `Checked = False` funcionam com `TabStop = False`.

Teria alguma forma em que o `TabStop = False` seja respeitado para todos RadioButtons, independente do Checked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testando essa situação aqui resolvi do seguinte modo:
 
No **ONSHOW** do form ***coloquei todos os RadioButtons.tabstop:= False*** 
e **no onclick de cada um** coloquei o mesmo codigo ***RadioButton1.TabStop:= False***. 
Dessa forma também funciona :) . 
Só uma outra maneira de chegar a um resultado :)

Answer (score 5):

Solução que encontrei foi forçar o <kbd>Tab</kbd> ou <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> no Evento OnKeyUp dos RadioButtons:

```
if (Key = VK_TAB) and (Shift = [ssShift]) then
begin
   Perform(WM_NEXTDLGCTL, 1, 0);
end
else if Key = VK_TAB then
begin
   Perform(WM_NEXTDLGCTL, 0, 0);
end;
```

Comment: Bom dia Melissa.. caramba.. nunca tinha reparado isso :) . Vivendo e aprendendo..Legal a sua solução.  Por outro lado , testando essa situação aqui resolvi do seguinte modo: No ONSHOW do form coloquei todos os RadioButtons.tabstop:= False e no onclick de cada um coloquei o mesmo codigo RadioButton1.TabStop:= False.  Dessa forma tambem funciona :) . Só uma outra maneira de chegar a um resultado :)

Comment: Legal! Ainda está em tempo para que eu use uma solução melhor, posta sua resposta tb, dependendo do q for melhor, marco a sua como aceita.

Comment: essa minha solução não ficou como esperava, pq é feito um "Tab fantasma" e dá pra ver, isso me incomoda um pouco ainda